# How does std::function know about calling convention?

Tags: c++, c++11, calling-convention

```
int __cdecl ccall(int i)
{
    wprintf(L"ccall(%d)", i);
    return 0;
}

int __stdcall stdcall(int i)
{
    wprintf(L"stdcall(%d)", i);
    return 0;
}

int __cdecl wmain(int argc, wchar_t **argv)
{
    std::function<int(int)> fnc = ccall;
    std::function<int(int)> fnstd = stdcall;

    fnc(10); // printed well
    fnstd(100); // printed well
    return 0;
}
```

I was concerned how do I assign a `__stdcall function` to `std::function` object.
But without any specifying calling convention, it looks like working fine. How can `std::function` know what calling convention is?

Comment: In the same way the compiler knows how to call the function without `std::function`. `std::function` uses type-erasure to create a tiny internal black-box that, when you call the `std::function` is asked to perform the "real" call, which the compiler has already figured out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`std::function` is able to store function pointers that use any calling convention.

§ 20.8.11.2:

> The function class template provides polymorphic wrappers that generalize the notion of a function pointer. Wrappers can store, copy, and call arbitrary callable objects (20.8.1), given a call signature (20.8.1), allowing functions to be ﬁrst-class objects.

As [John Calsbeek](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5696/john-calsbeek) [added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170087/how-does-stdfunction-know-about-calling-convention/10170224#comment13048868_10170224): There is nothing in particular in the standard concerning the calling conventions, but the compilers are doing their job and function pointers contain the information about the convention.

With function pointers you would need to specify the unusual calling convention:

```
typedef int(* c_ptr_t)(int);
typedef int(__stdcall * std_ptr_t)(int);

c_ptr_t c_ptr = ccall;
std_ptr_t std_ptr = stdcall;

// But std::function doesn't mind:
std::function<int(int)> fnc = c_ptr;
std::function<int(int)> fnstd = std_ptr;
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is technically an answer, since the C++ standard barely even mentions calling convention, and it certainly doesn't here. The answer is that `std::function` "remembers" the type of the function using the magic of type erasure, and function pointers in most reasonable compilers contain information about the calling convention used.

Comment: @JohnCalsbeek: You are right, there is nothing more detailed in the standard than mentioning the quoted part. The calling conventions are an uncharted territory, but compilers are well-behaved and do what is needed.

Comment: The closest thing is "C linkage". There the compiler just has to make it work - there's nothing in the standard that makes the programmer responsible. By extension, since the standard says nothing about calling conventions, that silence again makes it a compiler responsibility.

Comment: "function pointers contain the information about the convention" - specifically the type has that information, not the value. I know that with ARM/thumb interworking, the LSB of the function pointer switches the mode, so either one can be stored in a plain function pointer. But in general if you have two (or more) different calling conventions for a free function, there's nothing like that. It's because the function pointer value *doesn't* specify the convention that you need the different types in the snippet in this answer.