# Strip __attribute__((pcs("calling_convention"))) for use with std::function

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, std-function, decltype

I have the the following (stripped) code:

```
#include <functional>

namespace A{
  void __attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp"))) foo();
};

int main(){
  std::function<decltype(A::foo)> foo;
  return 0;
}
```

When I compile this with gcc, I get a warning:

```
warning: ignoring attributes on template argument 'void()' [-Wignored-attributes]
```

When I compile this with clang, I get an error:

```
error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'std::function<void () __attribute__((pcs("aapcs-vfp")))>'
```

What is the proper way to declare std::function ? I was reading on [How does std::function know about calling convention?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170087/how-does-stdfunction-know-about-calling-convention) and understand that std::function doesn't need to know about the **attribute**, so is there a way to strip the **attribute** from what decltype is returning ?

Comment: I don't think it's supported at all. You might have to add a wrapper function without attribute that calls `foo();`

Comment: wow, this is a big missing feature! I think Microsoft's version of calling conventions probably does let you include the calling convention in std::function.